# compute loss between outputs of a network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I wish to compute loss between output of classfier1 and output. I also want to compute loss bbetween classifier1 and actual labels.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense,Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape

def create_cnn_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    # Input layer
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    in_labels = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

    # First convolutional block
    x1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    x1= MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x1)
    # Classifier for the first block
    shape=x1.shape[1:]
    print(shape)
    x1=Flatten(name='fm1')(x1)
    classifier1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='classifier1')(x1)
    x = Reshape(shape)(x1)

    # Second convolutional block
    x2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x2)
    # Classifier for the second block
    shape=x2.shape[1:]
    print(shape)
    x2=Flatten(name='fm2')(x2)
    classifier2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='classifier2')(x2)
    x = Reshape(shape)(x2)

    # Third convolutional block
    x3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x3)
    # Classifier for the third block
    x3_flat=Flatten(name='fmf')(x3)

    # Final classification layer
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='classification_output')(x3_flat)

    # Create model
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs,in_labels], outputs=[classifier2, outputs,x2,x3_flat,domains])
    return model

input_shape = (20, 128, 1)
num_classes = 2

model_domain = create_cnn_model(input_shape, num_classes)

model_domain.summary()
```

I am not able to access multiple outputs in custom loss function by doing `y+pred[2]`, `y_pred[1]` etc, so I tried to predict the results then feed it back as labels. I'm having trouble on how two losses can be fed back into a single layer. Two loses here are namely `kl_loss` between `classifier1` and classification_output and binary cross entropy loss between `classifier1` and label.